# Как создать n количество строк для ввода данных?

Tags: python

Возник вопрос: Дается число n. Нужно создать n строк для ввода данных пользователем с сохранением этих данных. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = 3
x = []

for i in range(n):
    x.append(input('inp: '))

for i in x:
    print(i)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1):

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    for i in range(int(input())):
        file.write(input())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 3

strings = [input() for _ in range(n)]

print(strings)
```